# Filtering by using map value in cql Cassandra

Tags: collections, cassandra, filtering, cql

I'm trying to select records by filtering value on a map column.

```
name (text) | last (text) | languages(map<text:text>)
john | stith | {12:English, 123:Spanish}
Jane | Doe | {34:Italian, 123:Spanish}
```

I'm trying select records have only have Italian as a value. but on the documentation only shows how to get records from the by the key.

by filtering by Italian I should get Jane Doe on the example above. How can I accomplish my filtering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to create an index on value of the map.
Assuming an index on map value is created, filter the data using a value in the map

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE languages CONTAINS 'Italian';
```

To create an index on the values

```
CREATE INDEX mymapvalues ON tableName(languages);
```

see here for more info
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddlIndexColl.html